# Writing dynamic checkbox list, How can I submit the checked boxes?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am producing a list of students so a user can mark their absence. I want to have a form which has the checkbox and their name for each student on the users roster. I have code to generate that. Once I hit submit, how can I write a query that uses all the checked boxes to add the dates to the database with each student's id?

Here is my code:

```
$nameDB = "teacheasy";
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $usernameDB, $passwordDB, $nameDB);


$sqlListStudents = "SELECT CONCAT(last_name,', ',first_name) AS 'StudentName' FROM `students` WHERE teacher_id='" . $_SESSION['userId'] . "' ORDER BY last_name ASC;";
$resultListStudents = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlListStudents) or die("Bad Query: $sqlListStudents"); 
echo "<form method='post'>";
echo"<table>";
echo"<tr>
        <td><b>Mark Today's Absesences Only</b></td>
     </tr>";
$nameCount = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultListStudents)){
    echo"<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='student". $nameCount ."'>{$row['StudentName']}</td></tr>";
    $nameCount++;
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<button type='submit' name='submitAbsences' class='navButton'>Submit Absences</button>";
echo "</form>";

if(isset($_POST['submitAbsences'])){
    
}
```

Here is the output I have.
[Click this, I cant put pictures yet due to being a newer account.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipnOp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the names of the checkboxes to`name="students[]"` PHP can store all the names in an array by using the [list function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_list.asp). Once it is in an array you can update looping through the array.

Comment: do I need to declare that before hand? I tried adding it and doing a var_dump to check results but only got errors

Comment: @Matt You shouldn't need to declare it. If you post the errors I may be able to figure out what's wrong.